# Populate Excel Workbook Sheet with Rows from Master Sheet Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, copy, rows

I manage a large, ever-growing and changing contact list. I have a workbook with a master sheet containing 400+ names with headings in columns A-Q:

First | Last | Email | Phone | Mobile | Address | City | State | Zip | Tags | Community (and so on)

I want to be able to update my master list weekly and populate other tabs with filtered data by Community.

So, from the sheet "Master List" I want to pull all of the rows from A-Q to sheet "Twin Peaks Residents", only if the Community listed is "Twin Peaks" :-)

I was able to get counts of communities in another tab but copying rows is a different animal.

I was thinking of something like:

```
=IF('Master List'!K1="*Twin Peaks*")
```

...the rest of the formula... that results in only the rows with Twin Peaks listed as a contact's community would populate into the "Twin Peaks Residents" sheet.

The outcome is that once a week, I download a master csv file from an online database, paste it into the master sheet and the other tabs automatically populate based on their Community label in column K.

[Edit] Perhaps a simplification using fewer variable and images would be helpful. I'm going to add two screenshots of how I would like this to work in much more simple terms.
[Resulting Tab filtering for Chicago contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HurWd.png)
[Master sheet with all contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkqH.png)

Comment: Why not create a pivot table(s) based on the master sheet.  You can have several tabs with pivot tables pre-setup for specific outcomes.  As the master data changes the pivots can be refreshed.

Comment: I really shouldn't resist pivot tables like I do. Since they can be a bit of a learning curve, is there a specific technique you could suggest to create a pivot table on tabs that reference the master? Perhaps a good tutorial?

Comment: Frankly, a pivot would be easier than using formulas.  Just select all the data including the headings and create a pivot on another tab.  I usually immediately switch Report Layout (in Design Menu) to Tabular and Switch off subtotals.  Then try putting the fields you want to see in "Rows" and place Community in the filter.  Suspect you will be mostly there.  Plenty of good tutorials on the web - google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

As @Davo says you're probably best off creating a pivot table.

However, I have solved this problem using just formulas in the past, using helper columns.

1. Choose a helper column. It could be on another sheet, but I'm going to go with column X on your main sheet.
2. In `X2` set a formula: `=COUNTIFS(K$2:K2,"Twin Peaks")+1`
3. For convenience, name this column "TwinPeaksRowKey"
4. In your Twin Peaks sheet, set up columns same as your main sheet
5. Apply the formula in `'Twin Peaks'!A2`: `=IfNA(Index(Main!A:A, Xmatch(Row(),TwinPeaksRowKey)),"")`
6. Copy across and down as far as you need

You can refine this a bit - have a helper sheet with the community names in row 1 and have the `COUNTIFS` reference that.

Or… you could learn how to use pivot tables. I will too, someday.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm cautiously following your directions and have come across a few issues: 
Step 2 - after I enter the formula in X2 on the main sheet and hit enter, I see "0" in the cell which I assume is OK since this is just a helper column. I pulled the formula down the column which results in all "0"s. Step 5 - I get a #NAME? error. I substituted K:K for A:A since column K in the main sheet is the column that might contain the criteria "Twin Peaks". Still, I get the #NAME? error. Hmmmmmm. 

Comment: ah shoot, there was a typo. It should be `=COUNTIFS(K$2:K2....`, sorry

Comment: Thanks! Now I get a "1" in column X on the master and if I pull the formula down, the number increases when the community is listed. On the Twin Peaks Sheet, the column in cell A2, I am still seeing a #NAME? error. Any ideas? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK, did you name column `X`? You don't have to - you could use `XMATCH(ROW(),X:X)`

Comment: Yes, I named it as you suggested.

=IFNA(INDEX('All Contacts Dashboard'!K:K, XMATCH(ROW(),RowKey)),"")